# Log4j SMTP Appender configuration for elasticsearch in logging.yml

Tags: logging, elasticsearch, log4j, smtpappender

I am using `ES 1.7` on `Ubuntu 14.10`. My use case is that, whenever there is any kind of `error` occurs in `elasticsearch`, I would like to send an email to my team, e.g.

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "wrong_param": "energy"
    }
  }
}
```

This query is giving error like

```
All shards failed for phase: [query_fetch]
org.elasticsearch.search.SearchParseException: [my_index][0]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "wrong_param": "energy"
    }
  }
}
]]
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.parseSource(SearchService.java:747)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.createContext(SearchService.java:572)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.createAndPutContext(SearchService.java:544)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.executeFetchPhase(SearchService.java:385)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$11.call(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:333)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$11.call(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:330)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$23.run(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:559)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryParsingException: [enerknol] [query_string] query does not support [wrong_param]
    at org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryStringQueryParser.parse(QueryStringQueryParser.java:207)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryParseContext.parseInnerQuery(QueryParseContext.java:307)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.query.IndexQueryParserService.innerParse(IndexQueryParserService.java:382)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.query.IndexQueryParserService.parse(IndexQueryParserService.java:281)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.query.IndexQueryParserService.parse(IndexQueryParserService.java:276)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.query.QueryParseElement.parse(QueryParseElement.java:33)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.parseSource(SearchService.java:731)
```

I would like to send an email with this `error` as body, I have not been able to find any working example of using [`SMTPAppender`](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#SMTPAppender) with ES, I have changed my `logging.yml` file following this [blog](https://www.elastic.co/blog/logging-elasticsearch-events-with-logstash-and-elasticsearch) which refers to this [gist](https://gist.github.com/polyfractal/4968387).

My `logging.yml` file, the only change in this file is I have appended `smtpappender` at the end and added it to `rootLogger`

```
# you can override this using by setting a system property, for example -Des.logger.level=DEBUG
es.logger.level: INFO
rootLogger: ${es.logger.level}, console, file, smtpappender
logger:
  # log action execution errors for easier debugging
  action: DEBUG
  # reduce the logging for aws, too much is logged under the default INFO
  com.amazonaws: WARN
  org.apache.http: INFO

  # gateway
  #gateway: DEBUG
  #index.gateway: DEBUG

  # peer shard recovery
  #indices.recovery: DEBUG

  # discovery
  #discovery: TRACE

  index.search.slowlog: TRACE, index_search_slow_log_file
  index.indexing.slowlog: TRACE, index_indexing_slow_log_file

additivity:
  index.search.slowlog: false
  index.indexing.slowlog: false

appender:
  console:
    type: console
    layout:
      type: consolePattern
      conversionPattern: "[%d{ISO8601}][%-5p][%-25c] %m%n"

  file:
    type: dailyRollingFile
    file: ${path.logs}/${cluster.name}.log
    datePattern: "'.'yyyy-MM-dd"
    layout:
      type: pattern
      conversionPattern: "[%d{ISO8601}][%-5p][%-25c] %m%n"

  # Use the following log4j-extras RollingFileAppender to enable gzip compression of log files. 
  # For more information see https://logging.apache.org/log4j/extras/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/rolling/RollingFileAppender.html
  #file:
    #type: extrasRollingFile
    #file: ${path.logs}/${cluster.name}.log
    #rollingPolicy: timeBased
    #rollingPolicy.FileNamePattern: ${path.logs}/${cluster.name}.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.gz
    #layout:
      #type: pattern
      #conversionPattern: "[%d{ISO8601}][%-5p][%-25c] %m%n"

  index_search_slow_log_file:
    type: dailyRollingFile
    file: ${path.logs}/${cluster.name}_index_search_slowlog.log
    datePattern: "'.'yyyy-MM-dd"
    layout:
      type: pattern
      conversionPattern: "[%d{ISO8601}][%-5p][%-25c] %m%n"

  index_indexing_slow_log_file:
    type: dailyRollingFile
    file: ${path.logs}/${cluster.name}_index_indexing_slowlog.log
    datePattern: "'.'yyyy-MM-dd"
    layout:
      type: pattern
      conversionPattern: "[%d{ISO8601}][%-5p][%-25c] %m%n"

  smtpappender:
    type: org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender
    smtpHost: localhost
    smtpPort: 25
    from: mygmail
    to: companymail
    subject: something bad happened
    bufferSize : 20
    layout:
      type: pattern
      conversionPattern: "[%d{ISO8601}][%-5p][%-25c] %m%n"
```

This is not working, I also dont see any logs in ES after adding `smtpappender` which is kind of strange. Has anyone tried this? I would really appreciate any help regarding this.

Comment: From the [STMPAppender doc](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/net/SMTPAppender.html), "[...] by default, an email message will be sent when an ERROR or higher severity message is appended". Can you make sure that at least one ERROR log line is generated? You can also try to add the `smtpDebug: true` property to the appender to see if you can get any insights into what's going on at the STMP level.

Comment: Another issue might be that you don't have the `mail.jar` (i.e. JavaMail) file inside your `$ES/lib` folder. Could that be?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comments, I do not have `mail.jar` inside my `$ES/lib` which could be a problem, but I guess the real issue is SMTP port 25 is not open, `telnet localhost 25` throws error, also `Ubuntu 14.10` has reached end of life so I am going to upgrade to `15.04` and then I will surely let you know if Issue is resolved or not.